# Why does Link not work when I try to search for an movie in "/movie/:movieID"? It works when I refresh the page and when I search for a movie from "/"

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use Redux and Router here. After looking around for a solution, I think it is relevant to the question I have.

```
/*index.js*/
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
    ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <React.StrictMode>
            <Provider store= {store}>
                <App />
            </Provider>
        </React.StrictMode>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

The Movie ID parameter gets updated when I search for a new movie from let's say '/movie/12345' to '/movie/67891' but the I am not redirected to '/movie/67891' unless I refresh

```
/*App.js*/
    function App() {
        return (
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/' element={<Home/>} />
                <Route path='/movie/:movieID' element={<Movie/>} />
            </Routes>
                );
                   }
```

This is where I search for a movie, where I make a few API calls and do stuff. The Searchbar component is used on all pages. It works fine when I search for a movie in '/'...

```
/*Searchbar.js*/
    {
         results.map((obj) => (
             <TvShowContainer to={`/movie/${obj.id}`}>
                 <Thumbnail>
                     <ThumbnailImage src={(obj.poster_path === null) ? notFound : (obj.poster_path 
                      === undefined)?((obj.profile_path===null)? notFound: 
                      `${image_base}${search_size}/${obj.profile_path}`): 
                      `${image_base}${search_size}/${obj.poster_path}` } />
                 </Thumbnail>
                 <Name>{obj.name||obj.title}</Name>
                 <Rating>{obj.vote_average || "N/A"}</Rating>
                 </TvShowContainer>
                    ))
    }
```

Comment: Try this `<Route path='movie/:movieID' element={<Movie/>} />`

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: Try Moving `BrowserRouter` inside StrictMode in app.js

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: Add code for `<TvShowContainer />` in your question.

Comment: Solved it. I'm such an idiot. I forgot to add the movieID dependency to the dependency array of the useEffect hook...